# Change font size dynamically on specific paragraph <p> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following **JSFiddle** splits texts into individual paragraph `<p>` boxes with a set text limit.

---

Is it possible to change the text size in the boxes according to the select option through contenteditable while still allowing to edit, removing the text limit and remaining the dynamic size property?

**UPDATE 2: The boxes generated all need to be: 

 *"equal the same height and width"*

 and change when the font is updated dynamically, needing to be consistent across all elements.**

**UPDATE 3: The last generated paragraph is not equal to the other paragraphs with border size height.**

**UPDATE 4: All paragraphs need to be generated equally with the height attribute auto. The problem with the current answers is the that the last generated paragraph border also needs to equal the same height as the previous height border as the other paragraphs, including when changing the font size.**

**Update 5 [image]: Example of Problem with last divided paragraph height and border not equal to others.**

[image: Example of Problem with last divided paragraph height not equal to others.]

Link to [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/n9b6wju8/2/)

If a new fiddle could be provided, it would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding. 
Thank You!

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var targets = $('p'),
      property = this.dataset.property;
    targets.css(property, this.value);
  }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
var btn = document.getElementById('go'),
  textarea = document.getElementById('textarea1'),
  content = document.getElementById('content'),
  chunkSize = 100;
btn.addEventListener('click', initialDistribute);
content.addEventListener('keyup', handleKey);
content.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

function initialDistribute() {
  var text = textarea.value;
  while (content.hasChildNodes()) {
    content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
  }
  rearrange(text);
}

function rearrange(text) {
  var chunks = splitText(text, false);
  chunks.forEach(function(str, idx) {
    para = document.createElement('P');
    para.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    para.textContent = str;
    content.appendChild(para);
  });
}

function handleKey(e) {
  var para = e.target,
    position,
    key, fragment, overflow, remainingText;
  key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
  if (para.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  if (key != 13 && key != 8) {
    redistributeAuto(para);
    return;
  }
  position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  if (key == 13) {
    fragment = para.lastChild;
    overflow = fragment.textContent;
    fragment.parentNode.removeChild(fragment);
    remainingText = overflow + removeSiblings(para, false);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
  if (key == 8 && para.previousElementSibling && position == 0) {
    fragment = para.previousElementSibling;
    remainingText = removeSiblings(fragment, true);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
}

function handlePaste(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  overflow = e.target.textContent + removeSiblings(fragment, true);
  rearrange(remainingText);
}

function redistributeAuto(para) {
  var text = para.textContent,
    fullText;
  if (text.length > chunkSize) {
    fullText = removeSiblings(para, true);
  }
  rearrange(fullText);
}

function removeSiblings(elem, includeCurrent) {
  var text = '',
    next;
  if (includeCurrent && !elem.previousElementSibling) {
    parent = elem.parentNode;
    text = parent.textContent;
    while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
    }
  } else {
    elem = includeCurrent ? elem.previousElementSibling : elem;
    while (next = elem.nextSibling) {
      text += next.textContent;
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(next);
    }
  }
  return text;
}

function splitText(text, useRegex) {
  var chunks = [],
    i, textSize, boundary = 0;
  if (useRegex) {
    var regex = new RegExp('.{1,' + chunkSize + '}\\b', 'g');
    chunks = text.match(regex) || [];
  } else {
    for (i = 0, textSize = text.length; i < textSize; i = boundary) {
      boundary = i + chunkSize;
      if (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) == ' ') {
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      } else {
        while (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) != ' ') {
          boundary++;
        }
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      }
    }
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

```css
#text_land {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
textarea {
  width: 95%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
label select {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
h3 {
  margin: 1.2em 0;
}
div {
  margin: 1.2em;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  padding: .5em;
}
p {
  padding: 1.2em .5em;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="styles">
  <label>Font-size:
    <select data-property="font-size">
      <option disabled>
        Select font-size:
      </option>
      <option>
        smaller
      </option>
      <option>
        10px
      </option>
      <option>
        12px
      </option>
      <option>
        14px
      </option>
      <option>
        16px
      </option>
      <option>
        18px
      </option>
      <option>
        20px
      </option>
      <option>
        larger
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Paste text in the field below to divide text into paragraphs..</h3>
  <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder="Type text here, then press the button below." rows="5">
  </textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="go">Divide Text into Paragraphs</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 align="right">Divided Text Will Appear Below:</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the problem... You can set the font size to the parent element (#content{font-size:whatever}) and inherit it (#content p {font-size:inherit} ). If you set the font size in the parent if will apply to the the already added paragraphs AND the new ones when you add them.

(Changes in the fiddle: Selector in the change of the select, CSS selectors/properties for "p" and "#content p")

(Answer edited for "same height" paragraphs)
To get same height I added a sameheight(selector) function. I'm unsure about when you would like to trigger it, I've put it on select change and rearange(text). (Hope it helps. Fixed the height in function using outerHeight)
...and fiddle edited again: sameheight is also fired on window resize events.

```
function sameheight(selector){
var max_y=0;
var y=0;
$(selector).css('height','');
$(selector).each(function(){
  y=$(this).height();
  if(y>max_y) max_y=y;
});
$(selector).css('height',max_y);
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    //Lets target the parent element, instead of P. P will inherit it's font size (css)
    var targets = $('#content'),
      property = this.dataset.property;
    targets.css(property, this.value);
    sameheight('#content p');
  }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
$( window ).resize(function() {
    sameheight('#content p');
});
var btn = document.getElementById('go'),
  textarea = document.getElementById('textarea1'),
  content = document.getElementById('content'),
  chunkSize = 100;
btn.addEventListener('click', initialDistribute);
content.addEventListener('keyup', handleKey);
content.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

function initialDistribute() {
  var text = textarea.value;
  while (content.hasChildNodes()) {
    content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
  }
  rearrange(text);
}

function rearrange(text) {
  var chunks = splitText(text, false);
  chunks.forEach(function(str, idx) {
    para = document.createElement('P');
    para.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    para.textContent = str;
    content.appendChild(para);
  });
  sameheight('#content p');
}

function handleKey(e) {
  var para = e.target,
    position,
    key, fragment, overflow, remainingText;
  key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
  if (para.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  if (key != 13 && key != 8) {
    redistributeAuto(para);
    return;
  }
  position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  if (key == 13) {
    fragment = para.lastChild;
    overflow = fragment.textContent;
    fragment.parentNode.removeChild(fragment);
    remainingText = overflow + removeSiblings(para, false);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
  if (key == 8 && para.previousElementSibling && position == 0) {
    fragment = para.previousElementSibling;
    remainingText = removeSiblings(fragment, true);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
}

function handlePaste(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  overflow = e.target.textContent + removeSiblings(fragment, true);
  rearrange(remainingText);
}

function redistributeAuto(para) {
  var text = para.textContent,
    fullText;
  if (text.length > chunkSize) {
    fullText = removeSiblings(para, true);
  }
  rearrange(fullText);
}

function removeSiblings(elem, includeCurrent) {
  var text = '',
    next;
  if (includeCurrent && !elem.previousElementSibling) {
    parent = elem.parentNode;
    text = parent.textContent;
    while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
    }
  } else {
    elem = includeCurrent ? elem.previousElementSibling : elem;
    while (next = elem.nextSibling) {
      text += next.textContent;
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(next);
    }
  }
  return text;
}

function splitText(text, useRegex) {
  var chunks = [],
    i, textSize, boundary = 0;
  if (useRegex) {
    var regex = new RegExp('.{1,' + chunkSize + '}\\b', 'g');
    chunks = text.match(regex) || [];
  } else {
    for (i = 0, textSize = text.length; i < textSize; i = boundary) {
      boundary = i + chunkSize;
      if (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) == ' ') {
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      } else {
        while (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) != ' ') {
          boundary++;
        }
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      }
    }
  }
  return chunks;
}

 function sameheight(selector){
var max_y=0;
var y=0;
$(selector).css('height','');
$(selector).each(function(){
  y=$(this).outerHeight();
  if(y>max_y) max_y=y;
});
$(selector).css('height',max_y);
  }
```

```css
#text_land {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
textarea {
  width: 95%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
label select {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
h3 {
  margin: 1.2em 0;
}
div {
  margin: 1.2em;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  padding: .5em;
}
p {
 /*Here the sliles for OTHER paragraphs*/
}
#content p {
  font-size:inherit;/*So it gets the font size set on the #content div*/
  padding: 1.2em .5em;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="styles">
  <label>Font-size:
    <select data-property="font-size">
      <option disabled>
        Select font-size:
      </option>
      <option>
        smaller
      </option>
      <option>
        10px
      </option>
      <option>
        12px
      </option>
      <option>
        14px
      </option>
      <option>
        16px
      </option>
      <option>
        18px
      </option>
      <option>
        20px
      </option>
      <option>
        larger
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Paste text in the field below to divide text into paragraphs..</h3>
  <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder="Type text here, then press the button below." rows="5">
  </textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="go">Divide Text into Paragraphs</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 align="right">Divided Text Will Appear Below:</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem occurring  is when importing text the last paragraph in not equal to the other dynamic paragraphs in border height.

Comment: Sorry, can't see it. I see last paragraph border the same as other paragraphs. Do you mean that you want all the paragraphs with the same height even if it means that the the shorters ones will have white space at their bottom? If not, please add an screenshot of the "undesired" effect.

Comment: Please refer to Update 5 above. This displays the problem that the last divided paragraph has. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed. I was using height spite of outer height. Check it now :) @Dave

Comment: However, text is hidden when page is re-sized and is hidden due to the overflow property. Therefore, is it possible to resolve this issue? Thank You!

Comment: Yes. Just fire up the sameheight(selector) function whenever you need... for example on window resize :)

Answer (score 10):

Here you go **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9b6wju8/3/)**

```
$('#FontSize').change(function(){
var fontsize = $(this).val();
$('textarea').css('fontSize',fontsize);
});
```

Comment: However, when adding a new dynamic paragraph from pressing enter in the previous paragraph, the next paragraph text is different in size.

Comment: However, is it possible to keep the paragraph width and height and only change the text size, so it overflows into the next paragraph as the dynamic text size?

Comment: Yes, however, keep the paragraph width and height constraints for each dynamic paragraph

Comment: see this [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n9b6wju8/5/) , if I understand right you want this, right?

Comment: Please see the updated version. https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/n9b6wju8/6/ Basically, when you dynamically create paragraphs and resize using the dropdown option, the text is flowing over each other and not flowing into the next paragraph.

Comment: yep, i got it, well you must remove `height` from `p` property, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n9b6wju8/8/)

Comment: However, the last paragraph is a different size compared to the other paragraphs. Is it possible to keep all the paragraphs an equal size? Thank you.

Comment: yep, set `min-height` for `p` as i see your paragraph has almost `138px` height, so set `min-height:138px` for `p` like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9b6wju8/10/)

Comment: However, when making the font size smaller, there is a gap in each paragraph box. Can the text from the other boxes flow into where the gaps are present automatically?

Comment: well if you do this so it will not equal because you want to set height automatically when text end, right? now you should choose what you want, want a equal paragraph or automatically height for each paragraph.

Comment: Yes, each paragraph needs to be equal while still allowing text size adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="styles">
    <label>Font-size: <select data-property="font-size" 
     onchange="$('#textarea1').css('font-size',this.value)">
        <option disabled>Select font-size:</option>
        <option>smaller</option>
        <option>10px</option>
        <option>12px</option>
        <option>14px</option>
        <option>16px</option>
        <option>18px</option>
        <option>20px</option>
        <option>larger</option>
    </select></label>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Paste text in the field below to divide text into paragraphs..</h3>
    <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder=
    "Type text here, then press the button below." rows="5"> Test text
</textarea><br>
    <br>
    <button id="go">Divide Text into Paragraphs</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe i have the answer for you:

```
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var targets = $('p'),
      property = this.dataset.property;
    $("#content").css({'font-size': this.value});
  }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

I changed the function in order to set the font-size to the div rather that the paragraph. Is this what you wanted? As it is what i gathered from the info provided.

https://jsfiddle.net/n9b6wju8/14/

Comment: However, the last generated paragraph is not the same size as the other paragraphs. Is it possible to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: They are the same size. https://gyazo.com/ae6b7705e717332d5383b093c7bf0bee See the GIF i have just made, showing it

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a dynamic `style` element into the DOM and update it with the font size you're after. You could use an MV* framework to update its content.

```
$('#FontSize').change(function(){
    var fontsize = $(this).val();
    $('#style').remove(); //yes, there are better ways to update its content
    $('head').append('<style id="style">#content { font-size: '+fontsize + '}</style>');
});
```

Fiddled: https://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/m75gre8o/1/

Comment: The problem needing to be solved is all paragraphs need to equal the same height including the shorter dynamically generated paragraphs with the borders all equalling the same height when resized.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

`$('#FontSize').change(function(){
    var fontsize = $(this).val();
    $('textarea').css('fontSize',fontsize);
});`

Answer (score 0):

To change of font size of the div and text area:

```
  $(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            var fontsize = $(this).val();
            $('#textarea1').css('fontSize',fontsize);
            $('#content').css('fontSize',fontsize);
        }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  });
```

to keep the height of your text area: in CSS

```
textarea {
    width: 95%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

use `px` aslo instead `em`

Comment: However, when applying the new font size, the text changes. Though, when editing one of the paragraphs the text reverts back to a small font size. Also, the width of the paragraphs can no longer be set. Is it possible to resolve this issue? Thank You!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mgpvstqt/ (my previos link was not updated, sorry my fault). I guess i don't get your problem, of what part does it revert back to small font size? is it in the `textarea` or  in the `content`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fork of your fiddle and have edited(added) the event handler of select. I have added some code in their which maintains the font-size of editable p elements. Using that reference you can then apply all your styles as per your requirement.

Don't forget to mark it right and upvote if you find my answer right.

[JS Fiddle Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/zu863rdx/3/)

```
  targets.parent().find('style').remove();
  $('<style>[contenteditable="true"]
  {'+property+':'+this.value+'}\n[contenteditable="true"]:focus{'+property+':'+this.value+'}</style>').prependTo(targets.parent());
  {'+property+':'+this.value+'}[contenteditable="true"]:focus{'+property+':'+this.value+'}</style>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('#FontSize').change(function(){
var fontsize = $(this).val();
$('textarea, #content p').css('fontSize',fontsize);
});

$('#go').click(function(){
var fontsize = $('#FontSize').val();
$('#content').css('fontSize',fontsize);
  
});


$(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        var targets = $('p'),
            property = this.dataset.property;
        targets.css(property, this.value);
    }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
var btn = document.getElementById('go'),
    textarea = document.getElementById('textarea1'),
    content = document.getElementById('content'),
    chunkSize = 400;
btn.addEventListener('click', initialDistribute);
content.addEventListener('keyup', handleKey);
content.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

function initialDistribute() {
    var text = textarea.value;
    while (content.hasChildNodes()) {
        content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
    }
    rearrange(text);
}

function rearrange(text) {
    var chunks = splitText(text, false);
    chunks.forEach(function(str, idx) {
        para = document.createElement('P');
        para.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
        para.textContent = str;
        content.appendChild(para);
    });
}

function handleKey(e) {
    var para = e.target,
        position,
        key, fragment, overflow, remainingText;
    key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
    if (para.tagName != 'P') {
        return;
    }
    if (key != 13 && key != 8) {
        redistributeAuto(para);
        return;
    }
    position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
    if (key == 13) {
        fragment = para.lastChild;
        overflow = fragment.textContent;
        fragment.parentNode.removeChild(fragment);
        remainingText = overflow + removeSiblings(para, false);
        rearrange(remainingText);
    }
    if (key == 8 && para.previousElementSibling && position == 0) {
        fragment = para.previousElementSibling;
        remainingText = removeSiblings(fragment, true);
        rearrange(remainingText);
    }
}

function handlePaste(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName != 'P') {
        return;
    }
    overflow = e.target.textContent + removeSiblings(fragment, true);
    rearrange(remainingText);
}

function redistributeAuto(para) {
    var text = para.textContent,
        fullText;
    if (text.length > chunkSize) {
        fullText = removeSiblings(para, true);
    }
    rearrange(fullText);
}

function removeSiblings(elem, includeCurrent) {
    var text = '',
        next;
    if (includeCurrent && !elem.previousElementSibling) {
        parent = elem.parentNode;
        text = parent.textContent;
        while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
            parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
        }
    } else {
        elem = includeCurrent ? elem.previousElementSibling : elem;
        while (next = elem.nextSibling) {
            text += next.textContent;
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(next);
        }
    }
    return text;
}

function splitText(text, useRegex) {
    var chunks = [],
        i, textSize, boundary = 0;
    if (useRegex) {
        var regex = new RegExp('.{1,' + chunkSize + '}\\b', 'g');
        chunks = text.match(regex) || [];
    } else {
        for (i = 0, textSize = text.length; i < textSize; i = boundary) {
            boundary = i + chunkSize;
            if (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) == ' ') {
                chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
            } else {
                while (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) != ' ') {
                    boundary++;
                }
                chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
            }
        }
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

```css
#text_land {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

textarea {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 .5em;
}

label select {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

h3 {
    margin: 1.2em 0;
}

div {
    margin: 1.2em;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    padding: .5em;
}

p {
    padding: 1.2em .5em;
    margin: 1.4em 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="styles">
        <label>Font-size: 
        <select id="FontSize" data-property="font-size">
            <option disabled>
                Select font-size:
            </option>
            <option>
                smaller
            </option>
            <option>
                10px
            </option>
            <option>
                12px
            </option>
            <option>
                14px
            </option>
            <option>
                16px
            </option>
            <option>
                18px
            </option>
            <option>
                20px
            </option>
            <option>
                larger
            </option>
        </select></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Paste text in the field below to divide text into paragraphs..</h3>
        <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder=
        "Type text here, then press the button below." rows="5">
</textarea><br>
        <br>
        <button id="go">Divide Text into Paragraphs</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 align="right">Divided Text Will Appear Below:</h3>
        <hr>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for all paragraphs to be generated equally with the height attribute auto?

Comment: I did not understand you could explain a little more!